# Discord Java JDA | deleting data from SQLite / getting data from SQLite

Tags: java, sqlite, maven, discord, discord-jda

I'm trying to make a ticket-based support system and I would like to know how to read and delete data from a SQLite table.

The system will work like this:
You click on a reaction and the bot checks if you already have a dedicated channel, if not it will create one.
If you close the ticket by clicking on a reaction in your personal channel, the channel and your data will be deleted.

That's my code so far:

```
public void onMessageReactionAdd(MessageReactionAddEvent event) {
        
        if(!event.getUser().isBot()) {
            if(event.getChannel().getIdLong() == 747412032281772033l && event.getReactionEmote().getEmoji().equals("\uD83C\uDFAB")) {
            
                ResultSet set = LiteSQL.onQuery("SELECT channelid FROM ticketchans WHERE guildid = " + event.getGuild().getIdLong() + " AND userid = " + event.getUserIdLong());
                
                try {
                    Long user = set.getLong("userid");
                    if(!(user == event.getUserIdLong())){
                        
                        Category cat = ((GuildChannel) event.getChannel()).getParent();
                        TextChannel chan = cat.createTextChannel(event.getMember().getEffectiveName() + "'s TicketChannel").complete();
                        
                        EmbedBuilder builder = new EmbedBuilder();
                        builder.setDescription("Hi " + event.getMember().getAsMention() + ", bitte beschreibe hier detailiert dein Anliegen. Wenn du dein ticket schliessen willst klicke auf das X");
                        builder.setColor(Color.decode("#910cc9"));
                        chan.sendMessage(builder.build()).queue(Message -> {
                            Message.addReaction("\u274C").queue();
                        });
                        set.next();
                        LiteSQL.onUpdate("INSERT INTO ticketchans(guildid, channelid, userid) VALUES(" +
                                event.getGuild().getIdLong() + ", " + event.getChannel().getIdLong() + ", " + event.getUserIdLong() + ")");
                        
                        event.getChannel().sendMessage(event.getUser().getAsMention() + " TicketChannel eröffnet!").complete().delete().queueAfter(4, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
                        
                    }
                }catch (SQLException e) {}
            }
            
            if(event.getReactionEmote().getEmoji().equals("\u274C")) {
                
//delete data in table          event.getGuild().getGuildChannelById(event.getChannel().getIdLong()).delete().reason("").queue();
    
            }
}
}
```

Comment: And...what is the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Getting Data from SQLite**

*Most of this applies to SQL in general and isn't specific to SQLite.*

First off, a `SELECT` statement consists of different parts.

```
SELECT columns FROM table WHERE condition;
```

For `columns` you have to fill in the names of the columns you want to get from your `table`. Pretty self-explanatory.
If you want to select more than one column, you just have to list them with commas, like this:

```
SELECT column1, column2, column3 FROM table WHERE condition;
```

In order to select every column of your table you just write `*` instead of the columns.

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE condition;
```

Note: You can only access columns in your `ResultSet` if you selected them in your statement. If you select `channelid` you won't be able to get `userid`, unless you select it as well. (`SELECT channelid, userid FROM table WHERE condition;`)

You seem to understand the `WHERE` part so I will skip it. In case you need some more help or want to expand your usage of SQLite even more, you may check out some [tutorials](https://www.sqlitetutorial.net/) online.

Now, after writing your correct `SELECT` statement it's time to access the data in Java.

Therefore, you have to loop through your `ResultSet`.

```
ResultSet rs = LiteSQL.onQuery(
    "SELECT channelid, userid
    FROM ticketchans 
    WHERE guildid = " + event.getGuild().getIdLong() + " 
    AND userid = " + event.getUserIdLong()
);

// loop through the result set  
while (rs.next()) {  
    Long userid = rs.getLong("userid");   
    Long channelid = rs.getLong("channelid");   
}
```

You now have the data you need and can use it for whatever you want.

**Deleting Data from SQLite**

*Most of this applies to SQL in general and isn't specific to SQLite.*

The `DELETE` statement has a similar structure to the `SELECT` statement although it lacks the columns (of course).

```
DELETE FROM table WHERE condition;
```

As explained in the first part, you have to choose the table you want to delete data from and then narrow it down using conditions.

In your case, deleting a specific ticket would be like this:

```
DELETE FROM ticketchans WHERE guildid = GID and userid = UID and channelid = CID;
```

If you don't use all three IDs in the condition, you might end up deleting all tickets of a guild or of an user. Since the channelid is always unique you could possibly skip the `userid = UID` part, but the details are up to you.

As already mentioned, if you want more specific statements or need some variations, check out a [tutorial](https://www.sqlitetutorial.net/) of your liking. (The one provided is just an example, use whatever you are comfortable with.)

On another note: I would advice not using `.complete()` but `.queue()` instead.
If you want to know why and how, [check out this page.](https://github.com/DV8FromTheWorld/JDA/wiki/7)-Using-RestAction)